# QGIS - Zoom to current location

Tags: qgis, zoom

Is there a way of zooming to the current geographical location of the device running QGIS?

I want to be able to zoom to where I am at any time and maybe set the zoom extents too.

Comment: How did you get your location ? did your device have a GPS/GNSS or by other mean ?

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? They are some updates in 3.12 about GPS.

Comment: I am using 3.12 - will look into GPS updates.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way of zooming to the current geographical location of the device running QGIS?

Yes, sort of (for centering, not zooming).
Turn on the GPS Information Panel, connect to the Autodetect GPS option (which on Win10 will use the Windows Location Service in the absence of actual GPS hardware), and configure it similar to below to allow for map re-centering.

For zooming and setting extents, you likely would have to script your own project macro, which I don't know how to do at present.

[image: GPS Information Panel]

Comment: Thanks - as you say it sort of does what I want. My question was lacking detail. The use of the Win10 location is what I wanted, but it is a shame that I can't zoom to that point.

Comment: I've opened a Feature Request on the QGIS GitHub:https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34944

Comment: Appreciated. Thanks. This is all new to me.

Comment: If my response answered your question sufficiently, please upvote/accept it :)